# apache tile HTML rendering with empty <a></a>

Tags: html, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am having a very strange problem with HTML.

On my backend, the problem part is like this.

```
        <div class="content">
            <a href="detail.html"></a>
            <img src="assets/img/tmp/img.png" alt=""></img>
        </div><!-- /.content -->
```

On the brower(Google chrome) view source

> ```
>         <div class="content">
>             <a href="detail.html"/>
>             <img src="assets/img/tmp/img.png" alt=""></img>
>
>         </div><!-- /.content -->
> ```

but when inspect element

```
        <div class="content">
            <a href="detail.html">
            <img src="assets/img/tmp/img.png" alt=""></img></a>

        </div><!-- /.content -->
```

as you can see the  tag is interpreted differently, and it caused a lot of problems, any ideas why this happens?
but when i add `<a href="detail.html">><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></a>`  in backend the problem solves.However, instead of put this everywhere, is there any other way i can solve it

I am using apache tile in spring mvc with html header like below

```
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML"     doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
```

Comment: Are you saying a structure like `<a href="..."></a>` gets transferred as `<a href=".."/>`? Yes, that is not good. Unless the page is served up with an xml MIME type. In HMTL, `<a href=".."/>` is just a start tag with an error in it.

Comment: yes, that's what is happening, it got collapsed. is there a way i can disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. the template file i wrote using the jspx extension, where i should use jsp instead. i thought the extension doesnt really matter, since tiles will compile the file regardless the extension. Hope it could help others to fish out the same issues :)